# posting picture using jquery but can't get proper way to get picture element value

Tags: php, jquery

here is my html code

```html
  WELCOME Registration<br/>
  <strong>Select File to UPLOAD </strong>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" ><br/><br/>
  <input type="submit" id="sub" value="Registration">
  
  <div id="result">
  </div>
```

and this is my jquery code to get that image element

```html
   <script>
   
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#sub").click(function(){
  //--------------------
  var fd = new FormData();   
  var file = $("#file");
  //fd.append('file', value );
  //problem is the above code is not working giving error and not uploading picture
  //test.php is working fine , when i echo image then it show empty mean
  //picture is not post to test.php is something wrong i'm doing 
  $.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
    alert(data);
    }
  });
  //----------------------
 
  });
  });
 </script>
```

problem is the above code is not working giving error and not uploading picture
        test.php is working fine , when i echo image then it show empty mean
        picture is not post to test.php is something wrong i'm doing

Comment: The first issue is that you're not populating the `FormData` with any information. You then need to write the PHP code to deal with the request. See the question I marked as a duplicate for details on exactly how you do both of these.

Comment: yeah thank you , i made changes with my code now it's working